# How to use multiple CasperJS modules in one file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to use the CasperJS [tester module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html) and the [casper module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html) in one file. I would prefer to simply use the tester module, but I need to automate clicks. Here is what I have:

```
var config = {
  url: 'http://telluswho2.herokuapp.com/',
};

casper.test.begin('Home page tests', 6, function suite(test) {

  casper.start(config.url, function() {

    test.assertTitleMatch(/TellUsWho2/, "TellUsWho2 homepage title is the one expected");
    test.assertExists('nav.navbar', 'Navbar Exists');
    test.assertElementCount('ul.navbar-nav', 1);
    test.assertSelectorHasText('a.navbar-brand', 'TellUsWho2');
    test.assertExists('h1.brand-heading', 'TellUsWho2 brand heading exists');
    test.assertVisible('footer');

  }).run(function() {
    test.done();
  });

});


casper.test.begin('Test if research page links to NJIT\'s homepage', 1, function suite(test) {

  casper.start(config.url, function() {

    this.click('a.btn-lg:nth-child(3)');
    test.comment('Clicking the login link...');

    casper.then(function () {
      test.assertTitleMatch(/New Jersey Institute of Technology/, "NJIT's homepage title is the one expected");
    });

  }).run(function() {
    test.done();
  });

});
```

I am assuming the click action is never done because I need to use another module. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple casper instances in one file? What is the limitation that you want to work around? `casper` and `casper.test` are meant to be used together. I don't see where your problem lies. Please describe it in detail by editing your question.

Comment: `this.click('a.btn-lg:nth-child(3)');` won't work without getting a casper instance, and I am not sure how to do that with my current code. @ArtjomB.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that it works when the first `test.begin` is commented out? I don't see why that would be the case, since the first test case isn't logging you in or doing something else with the session.